# How to harden nginx vhosts (hosting WordPress) from other users in hacked WP installs

Tags: nginx, php, virtualhost, php-fpm, php5

**Overview:**
I have a dozen or so WP installs hosted on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, w/ PHP 5.5.9 & Nginx 1.4.6.  MySQL runs on alternate node, not on public network.

**Goal:**
To have directories & files of each WP install NOT be world-readable.  If a malicious user gets access to a particular WP install, I can't have them be able to navigate to an alternate WP install and read DB credentials.

**Details:**
Nginx runs as www-data.  A user, with no shell, is created for each vhost.  Each vhost supports a single WP install.  PHP-FPM pools run specific to each user / vhost.  PHP-FPM pools connect w/ Nginx via socks, not the loopback IP.

Reading the following [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-restrict-wordpress-file-permissions/) article, I have attempted to set file permissions as follows:
**Files - 640**
**Directories - 750**

When I configure permissions as such, Nginx, running as www-data, can no longer correctly access the WP files.  If I set permissions back to **644** & **755**, everything works as expected.

Sites are installed in the following structure:
**/var/www/site1.com/public

/var/www/site2.com/public

/var/www/site3.com/public**
and so on.

Each directory is owned by the corresponding user & user group. ie:
**site1-com:site1-com /var/www/site1.com**

We've had a WP site get hacked, and they were able to get a php file manager script onto the server.  My understanding is that this script is being run by user www-data.  (Checked w/ `ps aux`)  If that's true, that I suspect the malicious user could access all other WP installs via their php file manager script.

How can I improve my permission setup to harden security?  I'm open to all suggestions, even if it means re-configuring the entire stack install.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partitioning the machine is the best solution but PHP's `open_basedir` directive will already prevent the PHP scripts from accessing other users' directory.

Comment: use OS level containers to separate your users' environments.

Comment: Docker, ie OS level containers like LXC, would be perfect for this, like Zeb said. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC  http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Another option which is a bit lighter is to use PHP-FPM's chroot feature to run the PHP-FPM pool inside chroot. However, it requires setting up the chroot environment, where you need essential binaries and libraries, and also devices and `/proc` and `/sys` set up. This isn't an easy task to do. I'm not sure if there is a guide of doing that. I did it by trial and error method...

Comment: Thank you everyone for the details.  @Zeb - I was thinking about running with Vagrant, since it's a platform that we're all already familiar with at our office.

Comment: @Tim - I have minimal experience with Docker, but from what I understand, it's containers are very similar to Vagrant's boxes.  I'll do some further research today.  Appreciate the advice.  

Thank you very much again, everyone.